# How does purchasing tiles affect cultural border expansion?

Tags: civilization-6

As far as I know, borders can grow when a certain amount of culture is accumulated in that city.

But how does purchasing tiles affect this cultural accumulation? Do the accumulated culture become nullified and start over or are they kept and carried over to the next new tile?

Comment: This is a great question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to test this myself and confirm that a few Reddit threads, [including this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/5griu3/its_really_dumb_that_buying_a_tile_resets_border/), match my observations.

If you buy a tile, it *does not* reset the culture progress towards acquiring a new tile. However, it *does* increase the amount of culture required to claim the next tile, but all progress is retained.

Comment from the thread:

> It doesn't reset growth.
>
> However, if you're at, say, 50/60 culture needed to expand, and you'll expand, in, let's say 2 turns, and you buy a tile... any tile... suddenly you're at 50/120 culture to expand, and you'll not expand for 14 turns.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear and concise answer. Do you know how to check the actual number for this cultural border? I actually had been trying to check this number but didn’t manage to find how.

Comment: I can't recall off the top of my head if you can check. If I have to guess, it's more of a hidden value and you would just see a change in the number of turns until a new border tile is acquired.

Comment: Is this also true when you're buying the pink tile, the one that would be aquired next? So, does the progress swap over?

Comment: As far as I am aware, yes. Because it's just your progress that shifts